# Conditionally concatenate strings in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe that looks like:

df:

```
      Source    Text    
      Agent     aa      
      Agent     ab      
      Visitor   ac      
      Agent     ad      
      Visitor   ae      
      Visitor   ba      
      Visitor   bb      
      Agent     bc      
      Agent     bd      
      Agent     be
```

I would like to create a new dataframe that looks the following:

```
      Source    Text    
      Agent     aa ab   
      Visitor   ac      
      Agent     ad      
      Visitor   ae ba bb 
      Agent     bc bd be
```

So, for each new instance of an agent/visitor talking I want to concatenate the text of the different things one person said in a new cell.

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519697/python-pandas-groupby-conditional-concatenate-strings-into-multiple-columns), however this is too specific and I don't see how to apply this to my dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `Series` which is create by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) of shifted column `Source` by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) with `join`, last use double [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) - first for remove first level of MultiIndex and second for column from `Source`:

```
g = df['Source'].ne(df['Source'].shift()).cumsum()
df1 = (df.groupby([g, 'Source'])['Text']
         .apply(' '.join)
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
    Source      Text
0    Agent     aa ab
1  Visitor        ac
2    Agent        ad
3  Visitor  ae ba bb
4    Agent  bc bd be
```

Comment: If I run this code, I get the following error: `TypeError: sequence item 12: expected str instance, float found`. What can I do to overcome this, given your code?

Comment: @Emil - I think there are missing values in column `Text`, how working first remove them by `df = df.dropna(subset=['Text'])` and then apply my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
d=df.groupby("Source").groups
print(pd.DataFrame([ [k,' '.join(list(df.groupby("Source").get_group(k)["Text"]))] for k in d.keys() ],columns=["Source","Text"]))
```